# Does attacking zero strength units (eg. routed units, siege engines) require a full combat resolution?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Say I march into a territory that has either some routed units, or a siege engine (both having zero combat strength).

Does this start a full combat resolution- ie calling for support, playing house cards, or are the units instantly destroyed without combat?

It seems very plausible that if a combat round is necessary, the routed/siege units could still win the battle with support and house cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is still combat.** [The rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf) don't specifically mention attacking into a region with only routed units. Therefore we follow the default instructions: if you march into a region with enemy units, you have a combat. As you say, it's *plausible* that a routed army could win (which is good; if you don't want to lose the units, you can "waste" your good cards and support orders for the turn to keep them alive"), but obviously the attacker with units contributing to battle will have an advantage.